# Does Android support this kind of button which can press left and right

Tags: android, button, customization

[image: custom button]

Does Android support this kind of button like above ?

The button is for keypad and if press right, the text inside will move to right and change to next choice, otherwise press left, the text will move to left...

Any idea for this kind of button ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could make three versions of this button. 1. like it is, 2. what it looks like if you click on right side, 3. what it looks like if you click on left side. then you use an imageview to display the images and handle clicks yourself

Comment: see my answer which i have posted full solved layout

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please use the Switch button provided by android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not make a button acting different according to pressed area. but you can design a "HORIZONTAL" linear layout.

-Create 2 Imageviews (1 for left and 1 for right)
-Place these 2 control inside LinearLayout (HORIZONTAL orientation)
-set different onClick handler functions for each of these

Answer (score 0):

Try this using relativelayout::

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rlt1"   
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftArrowId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/larrow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightArrowId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rarrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

take two different arrow icons , one left and right and a background image as per your image

backgound image bg will be [image]

left arrow will be [image]

right arrow will be [image]